# Put each single args of a script to a new line [Bash]

Tags: bash, unix

Parsing texts in bash I frequently need to convert a set of arguments into lines of an output file.

For instance if I run:

```
theBinaryIamLookingFor "arg1" "arg2" "argument with some words"
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
arg1
arg2
argument with some words
```

I obviously need a native solution for most of the distributions, otherwise I know how to do it.

My main goal here is to optimize and clean the code I usually do made up with loops.

That's probably a silly question, but this is hell to search that on the web with very used keywords (new line, arguments...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only functionality specified by the POSIX sh standard:

```
printf '%s\n' "arg1" "arg2" "argument with some words"
```

---

If you want to ensure that each argument prints only one line, even if the arguments contain literal newlines, consider using the bash/ksh/zsh extension `printf %q` (which will also make non-ASCII characters and other content your terminal may otherwise not render visible), formatting content in a manner which the shell would `eval` back to its original values:

```
printf '%q\n' "arg1" "arg2" "argument with some words"
```

To see why this is important, consider `"arg1" "arg2" "argument with"$'\n'"a newline"`.

---

By contrast, if your goal is to generate output in a way that's easy to parse back into the exact same argument list that was originally given as input without unsafe practices such as `eval`, use NULs rather than newlines as delimiters with the format string `'%s\0'`; these are safe because, as command-line arguments are given as C strings and C strings are NUL-delimited, a NUL is the (only!) character that can't exist inside an argument's text (and thus can be safely used to delimit them).

Comment: Wow, very smart, just to be sure about the way it works, printf will run the FORMAT as long as it have remaining arguments ?